# Use a script to import a data item from excel into PowerDesigner

Tags: powerdesigner

As anyone used a VB script that imports a data item from an excel sheet into Power Designer using the EXECUTE COMMANDS functions. 
Trying to write the script, but dont know where to start.

Thank you

Comment: with the `Excel Import` under `Tools > Resources > Extensions > All Model Types...`?

Comment: Have gone into there - and seen the xem - how do I attach my import to it, or do I need to code the import - what I was originally trying was to create a vb script that would import the columns from excel using execute script